# How do you use the % modifier in a C# T-SQL query string?

Tags: c#, sql-server, modifier

I am trying to write a basic query in C# that includes the use of the '%' modifier.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT userName 
FROM tblUserInformation 
WHERE userName LIKE %@userNameQuery%
```

When I run that I get a SQL exception saying

> *You have a syntax error near @userNameQuery.*

I have encountered similar differences with SQL queries and C# sql query strings before but am unsure how to resolve this one. I have tried:

```
SELECT userID 
FROM tblUserInformation 
WHERE userName LIKE '%'@userNameQuery'%'
```

The one below does not throw an exception but returns no results. It should because I can run the same query against the database directly and it returns many results.

```
SELECT userName 
FROM tblUserInformation 
WHERE userName LIKE '%@userNameQuery%'
```

Am I doing this correctly?

Also, `@userNameQuery` is properly filled in with SqlParameter and is the correct data type etc.
Having tried both above and the second one works (returning no results) I am sure that there is no syntax error in my query string (extra semicolon or missing ").

Thank you for your time!

Comment: I strongly recommend to use SQL Parameters of the SQL Command. It keeps culture things. http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/lesson06

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass in the `%` in the value of the parameter, not have it in the query itself.

```
SELECT userName from tblUserInformation WHERE userName LIKE @userNameQuery
```

Where `@userNameQuery` would be like `%my query%`.

Comment: This works, thank you kind sir. I will mark as correct in 6 minutes :D

Answer (score 3):

Please try:

```
like '%' + @userNameQuery + '%'
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using it like this:

1. Write your `query` as `SELECT userName from tblUserInformation WHERE
   userName LIKE @userNameQuery`
2. Make sure the `string` you bind as the parameter `@userNameQuery` contains the necessary `%`, i.e. declare it as

   `var userName = @"%name%";`